# Custom time validation in Rails works on create, but not edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, time

I have a custom validation method that ensures an alarm can only be set in the future..

```
class Alarm < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :alarm_set_in_the_future

  def alarm_set_in_the_future
    if time <= DateTime.current
      errors.add(:alarm, "Please Choose A Future Date & Time")
    end
  end
```

This works great and the tests pass upon creating a new Alarm record. Awesome...

However, when editing an Alarm, the `time` variable gets set to the following datetime and I have no idea why!

```
2000-01-01 03:28:00 UTC
```

Consequently, the validation fails.

Where is that time parameter getting reset? Help!

Comment: maybe I'm looking at this wrong but shouldn't it be the other way around? "time >= Time.current"? So you are testing if it's greater than now?

Comment: Also, I know Time with a capital "T" is a reserved word. Is there any conflict with lower-case "t"? It may make sense to have a more descriptive column name like "alarm_time".

Comment: `Time` is not a reserved word. It's the name of a class.

Comment: Rails has 'DateTime.current', which is similar to Time.now in Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what's being submitted from your form. It seems unlikely that the problem lies in the validation itself.

Most likely, you're getting some bogus data from the form when saving the record. What is the value of `@alarm.time` in the controller before you save? What does the `params` hash look like?

Comment: The data type for the time attribute was "time" and not "datetime". Changing the datatype to datetime worked.